# Get all tags with specific option in term meta

Tags: wordpress, tags, metadata

Some of my tags have some custom `term meta` and I'm saving that meta with this function:

```
add_action ( 'edit_term', 'save_termmeta_tag');
   // save extra category extra fields callback function
function save_termmeta_tag( $term_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['Tag_meta'] ) ) {
        $t_id = $term_id;
        $tag_meta = get_option( "tag_$t_id");
        $tag_keys = array_keys($_POST['Tag_meta']);
            foreach ($tag_keys as $key){
            if (isset($_POST['Tag_meta'][$key])){
                $tag_meta[$key] = $_POST['Tag_meta'][$key];
            }
        }
        //save the option array
        update_option( "tag_$t_id", $tag_meta );
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to get all tag with a specific option like '`channel`'.

Is this possible, and how?

Answer (score -1):

```php
function get_term_with_option($opt) {
    $terms = array();
    // load all options
    $options = wp_load_alloptions();
    foreach($options as $k=>$v) {
        // find keys with prefix `tag_`
        if (strpos($k, 'tag_') === 0) {
            $v = maybe_unserialize($v);
            // check if has a meta key $opt
            if (is_array($v) && array_key_exists($opt, $v)) {
                $term = get_term(intval(str_replace('tag_', '', $k)));
                if (!is_wp_error($term)) {
                    $terms[] = $term;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $terms;
}

print_r(get_term_with_option('channel'));
```

Comment: It outputs `Array ( )`

Comment: could your provide the code how you save a `channel` option?

Comment: It's above `update_option( "tag_$t_id", $tag_meta );`

Comment: I used `update_option('tag_2', array('channel'=>1))`, it's ok

Comment: `channel` is a meta value ? not a key ?

Comment: `channel` is a value saved or not (it means that could be empty) in the option for each tag. Maybe what I need it's a simple query?!